# Application of the weak law of large numbers (Roulette)

Tags: probability-theory, applications, law-of-large-numbers

I am currently working on the following problem. Imagine the following situation: A player bets 1 dollar, and looses his bet with the probability of 19/37, but is given his bet and an extra dollar back with the probability 18/37. What is the probability that the casino looses money with this game on a (very) long run?

I wanted to use the weak law of large numbers. If the random variable $X_i$ is the money the player has after the $i$th game, then $X_i-X_{i-1}$ is the money he won in the $i$th game. So I need to look for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^\infty X_i - X_{i-1}> \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and the $X_i$ are Binomial distributed with parameters $p = 19/37$ and $q = 18/37$. Is this correct and how can I go on?

Comment: There is something wrong with $p$ and $q$. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Define the random variable as the profit of the casino. The profit is either 1 (the player lost) or -1 (the player won). Since the probability of the player losing is greater, the expected profit is positive. Then apply the law of large numbers.

Comment: Furthermore the $X_i$ should be independent and $0 < \mathbb E[X_1] = 19n/37 < \infty$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then
$\mathbb P\left(\left|\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i/n - 19n/37\right| > \epsilon\right) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ by the Weak Law of Large Numbers. This implies that $\mathbb P\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i = 19n^2/37 \right)= \mathbb P\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i/n  =  19n/37\right) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 1.$ Is this right?

Comment: The expected profit of the casino from bet $i$ is $E[X_i]=19/37-18/37>0$. Now the weak law of large numbers (assuming iid $X_i$) states the sample average converges in probability to its expectation, i.e., $\bar{x}\equiv n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\to E[X_i]$ (in prob). 

By definition of convergence in probability, for every $\epsilon>0$, $Pr(|\bar{x}-E[X_i]|>\epsilon)\to 0$. In other words, as $n\to\infty$, the probability that the casino makes a loss (if and only if $\bar{x}<0$) approaches 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Why is it important that $\mathbb E[X_i]$ is greater than $0$? For the weak law of large numbers it just needs to be in the intervall of $(-\infty,+\infty)$, right? And $\overline x < 0$ because over the long run the casino looses money iff the average profit of the casino per game is negative?

Comment: The average profit is total profit divided by $n$, so one is negative if the other is. Moreover, $E[X_i]>0$ or at least $E[X_i]}ge 0$ is important, because by the WLLN we know the sample average will be in the neighborhood of $E[X_i]$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, if $E[X_i]<0$ the average profit would become negative with probability approaching 1.

Comment: And that would be a contradiction, since we know that the probability that the casino looses money is gonna be $0$, right?

Comment: No, not exactly, sorry I'm still a bit confused. I don't understand, why it would be a problem that the average profit would become negative with prob. going to 1?

Comment: It is a problem, because it is not going to happen for the bet you describe above, which has a positive expected profit for the casino. I think you should try to understand the law of large numbers better. This is just a simple application of it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The LLN is still new for me. I'll work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us debunk several misconceptions that plague your analysis. First, the money $X_n$ that the player has after $n$ games is not binomially distributed since $X_n$ can be negative. However, $X_n=2Y_n-n$ where $Y_n$ is binomial $(n,p)$ with $p=18/37$ (and not $19/37$). Thus, $Y_n=Z_1+\cdots+Z_n$ where $(Z_n)$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli with parameter $p$, that is $P[Z_n=1]=p$ and $P[Z_n=0]=1-p$.

The law of large numbers (strong or weak) asserts that $Y_n/n\to E[Z_1]$ (almost surely or in probability), thus $X_n/n\to2E[Z_1]-1$. Now, $E[Z_1]=1\cdot p+0\cdot(1-p)=p$ hence $X_n/n\to2p-1$. Since $2p-1=-1/37\lt0$, this implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P[X_n/n\gt0]=0$.

Actual betting models take into account the fact that the fortunes of both players (the casino and the player) are finite, then one can be sure that the game ends with the ruin of either the player or the casino. The casino's fortune being immensely larger then the player's makes the ruin of the player overwhelmingly more probable. For $p\lt1/2$ as above, and for a player with initial fortune $f$ and a casino with initial fortune $F$, the probability of the player ruining the casino is
$R=(r^f-1)/(r^F-1)$, where $r=(1-p)/(1-2p)$. If $p=18/37$, then $r=19$ and $R\approx1/r^{F-f}$, which is *very* small.